# ANTLR4: How to get the position in the source with python3

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

I would like to use ANTLR4 to analyze COBOL files using a Python3 program.
To do so, I would need to know the position on which the token (lets say a MOVE statement) occurs in the file (at least the line and if possible also the character position). I need this especially, because I want to resolve COPY statements (similar to #include <> in C) and make sure I know in which part I am, while parsing the file.

I already searched here and found similar questions, but they don't seem to work for the python implementation (anymore). E.g. this one: [Previous Question about that topic, probably for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706327/getting-token-start-character-position-relative-to-the-beginning-of-file)

If I try this solution I get an error as soon as I call getStartIndex() or getSymbol() (AttributeError: 'StartRuleContext' object has no attribute 'getStartIndex').

Comment: The principle is still the same. Look at the interface/source of your python ANTLR4 runtime to see how the exact naming is.

Comment: Runtime API's are, as Mike mentions, largely the same, but never 100%. Have a look at the Python3 runtime: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and more correct way is to use `visitTerminal` method. ANTLR listener provides this method called when a terminal node is visited. You can then obtain your required info form the token.

```
    def visitTerminal(self, node: TerminalNode):
       terminal = node.getSymbol()
        self.print_symbol_detail(terminal)

    def print_symbol_detail(self, terminal, indent='\t'):
       print(indent + 'symbol=', terminal)
       print(indent + 'text=  ', terminal.text)
       print(indent + 'type=  ', terminal.type)
       print(indent + 'start= ', terminal.start)
       print(indent + 'stop=  ', terminal.stop)
       print(indent + 'line=  ', terminal.line)
       print(indent + 'column=', terminal.column)
       print('-'*75)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that only objects of type TerminalNodesImpl contain the required info. I came up with the following code, although I am not so happy that I have to use instanceof() to check if I have the right node type.
If somebody has a cleaner way to get to the info, please let me know.

```
class Cobol85PreprocessorPrintListener(Cobol85PreprocessorListener):
    def enterEveryRule(self, ctx):
        print("<< enterEveryRule type ", type(ctx))
        terminal= ctx
        depth= 0
        while terminal is not None and not isinstance(terminal, tree.Tree.TerminalNode):
            terminal= terminal.getChild(0)
            depth+= 1
        if terminal is not None:
            symbol= terminal.getSymbol()
            print('\tThe info was found in depth %d here:' % depth)
            self.printSymbolDetails(symbol, '\t\t')

    def printSymbolDetails(self, symbol, indent='\t'):
        print(indent + 'symbol=', symbol)
        print(indent + 'text=  ', symbol.text)
        print(indent + 'start= ', symbol.start)
        print(indent + 'stop=  ', symbol.stop)
        print(indent + 'line=  ', symbol.line)
        print(indent + 'column=', symbol.column)
```